# A sequence of floating divs shows irregular behavior halfway through

Tags: css, html, css-float

I hope someone can explain to me what is happening on the fourth row of this page:
http://www.derodewinkel.nl/shop-online.html?cat=1&filteritem=534

Instead of showing three products on that row, only one is shown.

- Each product is a div floating left.
- All have the same css classes except for the last product on each row.
- The last one adds the class "last", which declares a simple margin reset.

To me, it seems to happen at random and only in some occassions. There are other category pages with all the same classes which don't show this behavior. example: http://www.derodewinkel.nl/shop-online.html

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very strange. I'm interested to find out the answer myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in plain sight but subtle:

```
<span id="MainContent_ProductRepeater1_productoverview_ProductOverviewRepeater_productitem_6_OfferText_6" class="offerText">
```

This element causes one of the `.item` div's to be one pixel taller, which breaks the float sequence.

All the floats need to have the same height.

If you increase the height or min-height of `.item` by a few pixels, you will have a good fix.

One fix is to fix the height of one of the child block elements:

```
.productList .item .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

(see product.css)

If you fix the height of `.content`, then any optional inline elements that may appear will not affect the overall height of the `.item` block element.

Fixing the height is feasible in this case because your content is very predictable, price, item number, small brand logo, all very well defined.

Comment: That IS in plain sight! Thanks. It seems to be the smaller font size that is adding the extra pixel. Kinda weird

Comment: Not weird at all, happens all the time, but easy to overlook!

Comment: Sharp eye, nice find.

Answer (score 1):

It seems line 322 at master.css is causing the problem. I removed it and problem vanished. It may slightly alter other pages though.

```
318 #content {
319     position: relative;
320    float: right;
321     font-size: 13px;
322     line-height: 20px; ** REMOVING THIS FIXED IT
323     width: 760px;
324     margin-top: 10px;
325 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it! Marc also found the cause.

Comment: Actually, Marc found the exact problem and the correct solution. You are welcome and thank you for your kindness.